# How to ceate node with JSON in AEM through servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, aem, aem-6, crx

I have created a servlet with method post. Then, i used postman to request it with the JSON file in body.
Now i want to create node with JSON that i retrieved from servlet. How can i do that?
I know how to create node and setProperties but only String. I want to create node and setProperties with the JSON file like that

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5fc9dadaca52c28bb40011ee",
    "index": 0,
    "tags": [
      "laboris",
      "minim",
     ]
   },
   {
    "_id": "5fc9dada30930ef9d77c6d91",
    "index": 1,
    "tags": [
      "duis",
      "est",
     ]
   },
]
```

Please help me!

Comment: You want to whole json to be saved in the node properties or the json file? Please post the code of the servlet to better understand your requirement

Answer (score 0):

The Sling Post Servlet is what you're looking for. The import operation specifically:

https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#importing-content-structures-1

However, you need your JSON structure to be value pairs in the case of objects. Here's an example based on your sample json:

```
{
    "node": "parent",
    "childs": {
        "child1": {
            "_id": "5fc9dadaca52c28bb40011ee",
            "index": 0,
            "tags": [
                "laboris",
                "minim"
            ]
        },
        "child2": {
            "_id": "5fc9dada30930ef9d77c6d91",
            "index": 1,
            "tags": [
                "duis",
                "est"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

## From the Front End

Here's an example calling the sling post servlet with a json file. You can follow the same pattern in JS but specifying `:content` instead of `:contentFile`

```
curl http://localhost:4502/content/newTree \
  -u admin:admin \
  -F":operation=import" \
  -F":contentType=json" \
  -F":replace=true" \
  -F":replaceProperties=true" \
   -F":contentFile=@my-json-file.json"
```

## From the Back End

You can also create a POST request from the back end:

```java
@Component(
    service = Servlet.class,
    property = {
        ServletResolverConstants.SLING_SERVLET_METHODS + "=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_GET,
        ServletResolverConstants.SLING_SERVLET_PATHS + "=" + "/bin/services/test"
    })
public class Test extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    @Reference
    private SlingRequestProcessor requestProcessor;

    @Reference
    private RequestResponseFactory requestResponseFactory;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(final SlingHttpServletRequest request, final SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final Map<String, Object> parameters = ImmutableMap.of(
            ":operation", "import",
            ":contentType", "json",
            ":replaceProperties", "true",
            ":replace", "true",
            ":content", json
        );
        final HttpServletRequest postRequest = requestResponseFactory
            .createRequest(HttpConstants.METHOD_POST, "/content/newTree", parameters);
        final HttpServletResponse postResponse = requestResponseFactory.createResponse(output);

        try {
            requestProcessor.processRequest(postRequest, postResponse, request.getResourceResolver());
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```